# I can not connect my library to AIDE for Android

Tags: android

Here is MainActivity, in it I connect the library:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
        EditText argText;
        Button btAdd;

        static {
            System.loadLibrary("test");
        }

    public static native String my_printf();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            argText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.argText);
            btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdd);

            btAdd.setOnClickListener(new 
        View.OnClickListener() {


           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

              String a = argText.getText().toString();
              argText.setText(my_printf());

            }
            });
    }
}
```

I created the jni folder in Module/app/src/jni, in it the sources:

```
libtest.c

#include <string.h>
#include "TestJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myapp_MainActivity_my_printf(JNIEnv *env, jclass c) {
  return (*env) -> NewStringUTF(env, "Hello");
}
```

are

```
TestJNI.h

#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myapp_MainActivity_my_printf(JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

Also two .mk files:

```
Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and

```
Application.h

APP_ABI := all 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Did nothing else. The project compiles, but the application crashes. It turned out that the problem occurs when connecting the library and calling the native method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was clear, in AIDE for Android it was necessary to create an NDK project. Also there is a console NDK project, but we need an Application NDK project